# disconnect account with ethers.js

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, accounts

I created a **connect button** in my dapp  wich calls  '[eth_requestAccounts](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts)'  to connect an account to my dapp like this:

```
await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

or like this:

```
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
```

In both cases metamask pops up, and user is asked to connect his account.
Thats nice.

**However**, as Im trying to create a disconnect function button, I could not find a proper way to pop up metamask to disconnect a particular account.

This is inconvenient because I need to be able to trigger user interactions within my dapp's UI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to trigger MetaMask account disconnection in a similar way than triggering connection with the `window.metamask.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })` method.

[Here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#table-of-contents) is the list of methods that `window.metamask.request()` allows.

Either way, you can listen to the [disconnection event](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#disconnect) and perform your logic when your user manually disconnects from the MetaMask UI.